# Problems with controlling the behaviour of my table's cells in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to Objective C and I'm extremely lost with a table I'm working on. What I want is for when I click the cell it expands and shows me a subview which is another label and then when I click it again it hides the subview and the original text is shown. At the moment it all goes horribly wrong and I really don't know how I should be coding it. The premise is that I have a question which expands to reveal an answer, and I thought it'd be easy... Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Deselect cell
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

// create the subview and apply it to the current cell selected
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.text = @"OH";
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

// Toggle 'selected' state
BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];

// update the view that holds the table
[firstView beginUpdates];
[firstView endUpdates];

//Change cell contents
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

If anyone can provide some help, even better a code change to show me how I should go about this, that would be terrific as I'm at a loss and need to get this done in the next few hours! Eek.

Thanks!

Comment: are you facing with this code ? `BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];
`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by facing?

Comment: at the first click it will display the label, on second click what happens ? I think it won't return to previous state.

Comment: What exactly "goes horribly wrong".  More info would also be useful including your `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.  Also, why are you calling `beginUpdates/endUpdates` on a UIView rather than a UITableView?

Comment: it does return to the previous state at the moment, but I just want to be able to change the text that it displays on touch to show different information, and I thought that would be best achieved with a subview

Comment: @RoboticCat - By horribly wrong I mean it replaces the value in the cell selected with the value that's first in my array, which is 'HELLO'. I want to be able to choose what text replaces it. And to be honest, I'm really confused with this all so maybe I should be updating the UITableView as you say

Comment: @Creights - Nowhere in the code displayed is your text being set to the value of the array (it is being set to OH - a test string?).  Can you add the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are adding your label to the contentView **every** time you call this method, both when you select and deselect the cell.  The label only needs to be added when the cell is originally unselected and then it needs to be removed when it is touched again.  You will need to retain a reference to the label (or set a tag on it) so that you can call `removeFromSuperview`:

```
[label removeFromSuperview];
```

It's also not clear to me what happens if the cell is scrolled off-screen and re-used (while being selected); is the label added back to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? If so, why bother adding it here?

Secondly, please add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as that is likely where you are setting your text to your array value (so we can try and fix your real issue).

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks for making me think about it in that way!